# Changing a variable's value inside a class in python

Tags: python, class, object

I have a variable:

```
var_1 = 5
```

I pass it to a class:

```
class x():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.class_var_1 = val

object_1 = x(var_1)
```

I want to change `var_1`'s value using `class x`, but it won't change

```
object_1.class_var_1 = 3

print var_1
5
```

`var_1` isn't copied to `object_1.class_var_1` with a reference to `var_1`.

How do I change `var_1`'s value by changing `object_1.class_var_1`'s value?

Comment: You can't. Integers are immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Python `int` is immutable. The object can never change its value. Thus you need to re-bind the name to a different object. You'll need code like this:

```
var_1 = ...
```

Substitute whatever you like on the right hand side.

Comment: Ok, what if it is not a int but a bool?

Comment: If you are interested in booleans, why did you ask about `int`. But as it happens, Python booleans are also immutable.

Comment: I didnt know it would matter.

Comment: @alwbtc Booleans are immutable as well.

Comment: you can use a mutable object like a list (even if it contains one single int) or a custom object.

Comment: What do you mean integers are immutable? I just want to change the value of `var_1` by changing value of `object_1.class_var_1`. It shouldn't be that impossible

Comment: The `int` object is immutable. When you write `var_1 = ...` you re-bind the name `var_1` to a new object. That object might have a different value from the value that was previously bound.

Comment: but when you do `a = 5` and `b=a` and then `b=3`, `a` is also set to `3`. right???

Comment: No. You can only rebind `a` by writing `a = ...`. In the code above, after `b = a`, the names `a` and `b` are bound to the same object. An `int` with the value `5`. But then you rebind `b` to a new object, an `int` with the value `3`. Now `a` and `b` are bound to different objects. I think maybe it's time to go back to your text book and learn about name binding and immutability. Which book are you learning from?

Comment: sorry, earlier this morning i tried it on a dictionary object, and its keys' values were changed as i changed another variable. ok integers are immutable i get it.

Comment: Yes, dictionaries are mutable